# How to increment a row after x number of times

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I have a problem where I have to put a lot of values into a table that follows a pattern but I don't know where to start. I need it to look like this:

```
    table_id   second_id   type_id   default_value
    --------   ---------   -------   -------------
        1          1          1        'default'
        2          1          2        'default'
        3          1          4        'default'
        4          2          1        'default'
        5          2          2        'default'
        6          2          4        'default'
```

That pattern goes on for a while where the table_id increments each row, the second_id increments every three rows and the type_id goes through a cycle every three rows also. Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: how many such sets of rows do you have to generate?

Comment: I have to do it for two million rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmmm.  This is the first thing that comes to mind:

```
select row_number() over (order by id2.n, id3.n) as first_id,
       id2.n as second_id, id3.n as third_id,
       'default' as default_value
from generate_series(1, 10) id2(n) cross join
     (values (1), (2), (4)) id3(n);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select
  i+1 as table_id,
  i/3+1 as second_id,
  (array[1,2,4])[i%3+1] as type_id,
  'default' as default_value
from
  generate_series(0,29) as i;
```

Comment: For my taste, this looks more readable than version with window functions and cross join.